# замена текста в TextView

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть генератор, который выводит несколько слов с массива, при нажатии кнопки, но нужно что бы каждый раз при нажатии, ТекстВью перезаписывался, а на данный момент, при первом нажатии генерируется тест, а второй раз он подставляется, а нужно что бы перезаписывался, подскажите, спасибо!

```
public String jokes[] = {"text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text_gen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_gen);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copy);

    
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override public void onClick(View v){
        Random random=new Random();
        int x = 0;
         do {
            int num = random.nextInt(jokes.length);
             text_gen.append(jokes[num]);
             //System.out.println(jokes[num]);
            x++;
        } while(x <= 10);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теле цикла S = S + " " + jokes[num]; После выполнения цикла text_gen.setText(S); А перед циклом объяви String S ="";

```
text_gen.setText("");
```

Comment: SetText() - выведет только одно слово, и будет заменять только одно слово

Comment: Сколько слов туда запишите, столько и выведется

Comment: Проблема в том, что слов много, а выдает почему то одно именно в setText, не понимаю почему

Comment: Тогда используйте промежуточную переменную String, которую потом добавляйте к textview

Comment: Можно пример кода пожалуйста

Comment: В теле цикла S = S + " " + jokes[num]; После выполнения цикла text_gen.setText(S); А перед циклом объяви String S ="";